# Writing files to iPhone internal storage accessible for PC user via USB cable (Xamarin)

Tags: iphone, xamarin, internal-storage

I am building an iPhone scanner application for my company using Xamarin, C#. The environment is heavily restricted, no Bluetooth or wifi communication is allowed. The scanner would work offline, gathers the data. The question is how do I get the data out of the phone? All I have is the USB cable connected to a PC. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: with those restrictions, using an iPhone seems like an expensive waste.  Why not just use a USB camera or scanner?

Comment: Hi Jason, we do need the mobility. It is not document scanning but inventorization of goods. We need to reach out to true obscure locations with low lights.

Comment: For external storage, we have implemented it in each specific platform ,please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=windows for more details.